# How do you adjust notifications on the LG Nexus 4

Tags: notifications

I use to see notifications for Facebook and Snapchat on my phone but now I don't.  Can you tell me how to get this back.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic scenario:

1. You disabled the notification from the app itself.

   - So open the setting of the app and enable notification there
2. You removed the notification power of the app from system setting menu

   - Open settings -> Apps. Click on the name of the *required* app and make sure "Show notifications" is enabled.